How build mocha fraimwork for browser?
I need to change the code in the project mochajs
I know what I need to do, but I don't know how to build the es module for browser.
I used esbuild the project is not built correctly and does not run in the browser.
How can I build esm module in your project?
  const buildParams = {
        entryPoints: entryPoints,
        bundle: true,
        metafile: true,
        outfile: outfile,
        format: "esm",
        define,
        loader: { ".js": "jsx", ".json": "json", ".png": "file", ".jpeg": "file", ".jpg": "file", ".svg": "file", ".woff": "file" },
        color: true,
        minify: true,
        sourcemap: true,
        treeShaking: true,
        mainFields : [ 'module' , 'main' ],
        plugins: [
            glsl({
                minify: true
            }),
            aliasPlugin({
                '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
            }),
            polyfillNode({
                process: true,
                buffer: true,
                define
            }),
            cssModulesPlugin({
                v2: true,
                v2CssModulesOption: {
                    dashedIndents: true,
                    /**
                     * Optional. The currently supported segments are:
                     * [name] - the base name of the CSS file, without the extension
                     * [hash] - a hash of the full file path
                     * [local] - the original class name
                     */
                    pattern: `[name]_[local]__[hash]`
                }
            }),
        ]
    }

    let result = await esbuild.build(buildParams)
    console.log('BUILD: SUCCESS', result)
    console.timeEnd("⚡ [esbuild] Done")


